# how to recognize the type of the mobile keypad (normal or QWERTY) programmatically?

Tags: java-me

I want to know the type of the mobile keypad programmatically. Is there any way to track this. If yes, Please guide me to get this issue ?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Haven't tried this, so may  not work, but try and see.

According to [this link](http://knol.google.com/k/david-ehrmann/j2me-keycodes/1aqx1s1xle2uu/5#), J2ME handsets with QWERTY keyboards "almost always return their corresponding ASCII/UTF8 value [as `keyCode` parameter when the framework calls `Canvas.keyPressed()`]".  So try calling something like [`Canvas.getKeyName(65)`](http://download.oracle.com/javame/config/cldc/ref-impl/midp2.0/jsr118/javax/microedition/lcdui/Canvas.html#getKeyName%28int%29) (i.e. the letter 'A').

If it throws `IllegalArgumentException` you will know that 65 is not a valid `keyCode` for that device, therefore it's not a QWERTY handset.

Let me know if it works!